# ostream.write writes extra bytes into buffer

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm using ostream to serialize an object, but the write() method seems to write extra bytes into the buffer.

```
uint32_t id1=0x01;
uint32_t id2=0xdeadbeef;
std::stringstream sink;
sink.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&id1),sizeof(uint32_t));
print(sink); //01000000 - Correct
sink.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&id2),sizeof(uint32_t));
print(sink); //FFFFFFEFFFFFFFBEFFFFFFADFFFFFFDE - why?!

//print defined as follows:
static void print(std::ostream &sink){
    std::stringstream sk;
    sk << sink.rdbuf();
    std::string ss=sk.str();
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<ss.length();i++){
        printf("%02X", ss.c_str()[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm confused why those `FFFF` gets written into the buffer.

Comment: I [haven't been able](http://ideone.com/IqeGbP) to reproduce this. What type is `sink`? What system are you on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though `ss.c_str()[i]` is of type `char`, `printf` promotes its arguments to type `int`, so the extra `FFFFFF` are from the promotion to type `int`. Try `"%02hhX"` instead to tell `printf` to convert them to `unsigned char`s.

Another solution is to `ss.c_str()[i] & 0xFF` to mask them off. Also, note that `ss.c_str()[i]` can be simplified to `ss[i]`.

What is happening in your code is known as [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been debugging `ostream` for hours. Didn't realize it the `printf`'s problem. :-(